# Duda con valor seleccionado de ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

Estoy tratando de que un `ComboBox` dependa de otro `ComboBox` con datos de `SQL`. Así cargo el `List`:

```
    public List<Personas> asesores(int posicion)
    {
        List<Personas> salida = new List<Personas>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT a.id AS ID, a.nombre AS ASESOR " +
                "FROM provincias p " +
                "INNER JOIN asesores a " +
                "ON p.id = a.idProvincia " +
                "WHERE p.id = @prov";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prov", posicion);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"].ToString());
                        string nombre = dr["ASESOR"].ToString();
                        Personas p = new Personas(id, nombre);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }
        }
```

Este método uso para cargar el `ComboBox`:

```
    private void llenarAsesores()
    {
        int posicion = Convert.ToInt32(cmbProvincias.SelectedValue);
        if (posicion != 0)
        {
            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
            cmbAsesor.ValueMember = "ID";
            cmbAsesor.DisplayMember = "ASESOR";
            cmbAsesor.DataSource = conexionSQL.asesores(posicion);
        }
    }
```

Y así los ejecuto:

```
    private void menu1item1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cmbProvincias.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; ;
        this.cmbProvincias.SelectedIndex = -1;
        llenarProvincias();
        llenarAsesores();
    }
```

Pero, por algún motivo, cuando elijo un valor del primer `combobox` el segundo sigue trayendo los mismos datos, ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo? Dejo imágenes ilustrativas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no veo que tengas un evento en el changue de tu combo principal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te esta faltando el codigo del evento `SelectionChangeCommitted` del primer combo para que cambie el segundo

```
public void cmbProvincias_SelectionChangeCommitted(...) 
{
   llenarAsesores();
}
```

de esta forma cuando cambias la seleccion de la provincia volveras a cargar los asesores